# How to set MySQL exclusive locks on rows that remain effective after transaction commits?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, relational-database, innodb

I need to be able to set locks on database rows in transactions that are effective even after the transaction containing the set locks statement completes. Right now, I'm seeing that the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement is the way to set exclusive locks but these locks seem to be [released automatically](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) upon transaction commit? Is there a way to have locks set by `SELECT FOR UPDATE` remain in effect after the transaction commits so that I can manually release them in another transaction?

Comment: Row locks are released when you commit (or rollback). You may use explicit table locks, which are not released by commit or rollback, but these act differently than row locks, so you should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html Why do you need this? It sounds like it might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: See the _very rarely used_ `GET_LOCK()` function.  It can be useful for things that don't fit within the "transaction" model.